# using ruby , how can I load data from a csv file into an elasticsearch index?

Tags: ruby, curl, elasticsearch

I want to load data form a csv file into an elastic search index. I am not using the eleasticsearch gem (yet), just  a plain ruby script. Here it is:

```
CSV.open("candidates.csv", "r").each do |row| 
  #file = "candidates.csv"
  #file_data = file.read
  #csv_rows  = CSV.parse(file_data, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol)
  #csv_rows.each do |row| 
  curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/candidates/candidate" -d '
    {
     "first"   => row[:first],
     "last"   => row[:last],
     "designation"   => row[:designation],
     "company"   => row[:company],
     "city" => row[:city],
     "country" => row[:country],
     "email"   => row[:email],
     "phone"   => row[:phone],
     "experience"   => row[:experience]  
   }'
```

The error message is:

```
load.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

Is the approach completely wrong, i.e. sticking a "curl" request into the middle of a ruby script?

What is the best approach to do this, and how can it best be done?

Many thanks as always.

Comment: Is that `curl` command a shell command? Then you should put backticks around the command or use `system`. (And shouldn't there be a space between X and POST?)

Comment: I got lost of lines like this:
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   548  100   235  100   313    228    303  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   303
but no entires inot the index

Comment: thanks, still not quite there. Yes, back ticks were needed but no space between X and POST.